# Removing variable if not filled out

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a reference generator. People fills in some information, and then the generator sets up the text in the right way. Here's what I've got so far:

```
    $('#ref-button1').click(function () {
    var authorname = $('#bookAuthor').val();
        if (authorname == "") {
             $('.error').show();
             return false;
         }
    var booktitle = $('#bookTitle').val();
        if (booktitle == "") {
             $('.error').show();
            return false;
         }
    var year = $('#bookYear').val();
        if (year == "") {
             $('.error').show();
            return false;
         }
    var place = $('#bookPlace').val();
        if (place == "") {
            $('.error').show();
            return false;
         }
    var publisher = $('#bookPublisher').val();
        if (publisher == "") {
             $('.error').show();
            return false;
         }
    var edition = $('#bookEdition').val();
    var page = $('#bookPage').val();
    var completeString1 = authorname + '&nbsp;' + '(' + year + '),' + '&nbsp;' + '<i>' + booktitle + '</i>' + ',&nbsp;' + edition + '&nbsp;ed.,&nbsp;' + place + ':&nbsp;' + publisher + ',&nbsp;' + page;

    $('.error').hide();
    $('#output').empty();
    $('#output').append(completeString1);
});
```

As you see, I have 5 variables that have to be filled out, and 2 that don't. I create the entire string in completeString1, where I also put in the commas and so on. I know this is probably not the easiest way to do, but it is how I could do it. My problem now, is that my completeString1 will still contain and print "ed.," even if I don't fill out the variable.

So my question is: How can I leave out that bit of the variable, given that it is not filled out?

Comment: Well the code is not optimal as you say, but you do have the `if (variable == "")` part nailed down. So, use the same technique when creating `completeString1`.

Comment: and you can group your 'not empty' validation in 1 if statement, with or operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got is that you have problem with "edition" variable. So you need to change the way you assign the value to it:

```
var edition = $('#bookEdition').val() != "" ? ($('#bookEdition').val() + '&nbsp;ed.,&nbsp;') : "";
```

And then, update `completeString1` setting to:

```
var completeString1 = authorname + '&nbsp;' + '(' + year + '),' + '&nbsp;' + '<i>' + booktitle + '</i>' + ',&nbsp;' + edition + place + ':&nbsp;' + publisher + ',&nbsp;' + page;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional operator:

```
(edition?'&nbsp;ed.,&nbsp;':'')
```

If edition is true it will return the first value after the questionmark, else the value after the colon.
This will work since "" (an empty string) evaluates as false.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the if-blocks which only operate when a value is filled in, just create your string in there:

```
var resultstring = "";
$('#ref-button1').click(function () {
var authorname = $('#bookAuthor').val();
    if (authorname == "") {
         $('.error').show();
         resultstring = authorname + '&nbsp;' + '(' + year + '),' + '&nbsp;'
    }
```

Just build the string in the 5 steps, and no text will be added if the if-evaluation is `false`.